# Как изменить стиль input при каком-то условии в php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

Я через php проверяю наличие строк в таблице mysql и ввожу на экран количество строк.
Как можно изменить стиль `input` при условии если строки в таблице `mysql = 0`?

```
global $wpdb;
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$post_name = get_the_title();
$wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM product_keys WHERE product=' . $post_id);
$count = $wpdb->num_rows;
if($wpdb->num_rows === 0){
    echo "Нет в наличии";
    mail("armantepnanc@gmail.com", "Ключи закончиличь!", "У товара $post_name(ID - $post_id) ключи закончились!!");
    //Тут должен быть код который изменяет стиль
}
else if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){
    echo  $wpdb->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: вопрос немного редактировал

Comment: Вы даже не проверяете 1) установлено ли соединение 2) выполнен ли запрос без ошибок. И в приведённом коде нет NULL, так что яснее-то не стало.

Comment: тут нет смысла проверить установлен соединение потому-что это Wordpress

Comment: Вам бы для начала найти шаблон в теме. И там можно подправить. Например добавлять `css`-класс при каком либо условии.

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему это нужно делать через фронт. Например, для переноса рендера и всяких условий по этому рендеру на фронт, сделайте небольшой API для обмена данными.
Ну а вообще, можно захардкодить, ведь у вас же рендер инпута где-то прописан. Там и вставляйте:

```
<input name='name' type='text' class="input <?php $count > 0 ? '' : 'classIfCount0' ?>">
```